# Restrict access to my App Engine PHP app for set of Google accounts?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is there a way I can restrict access to my App Engine PHP app for only a certain set of Google account holders (who are logged in at the time of course)? The additional requirement is the PHP scripts on my site will be called via AJAX. It's fine for the users not to see a Google login prompt as they are internal users and will know that they are supposed to be already logged in.

Looking at the PHP app.yaml https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#handlers_login and User auth info https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/#choosing_an_authentication_option I wasn't clear how this could be achieved (apart for Admin roles which are too permissive for these users)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very crude/simple solution would be implemented like this:

In app.yaml, add something like this

```
- url: .*
  script: main.php
  login: required
```

Then in main.php, something like this

```
$user = \google\appengine\api\users\UserService::getCurrentUser();
if($user) {
    if(in_array($user->getEmail(), ['user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com'])) {
        // OK, user is allowed
    } else {
        // Logged in, but UNKNOWN user
    }
} else {
    // User not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use oauth to get users email address while authenticating and use that to allow a group of emails to qualify and raise oauthexception for others

Comment: Thanks. You mean as per Tom's example below, or some other way?

Comment: tom is using  appengine built in way to secure a url with form logging mechanism, its not oauth but will work as well I suppose. Oauth works against google accounts slightly cumbersome to do but its your choice really.